# Pine script simple condition statement

Tags: python, conditional-statements, pine-script, series

I am trying to convert a pine script to python.  I have a problem understanding these three lines of code:

```
trend = 1

trend := nz(trend[1], trend)

trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
```

My questions:
(1) In the statement (trend = 1), is trend a series or an integer constant?
(2) Based on the second statement (nz(trend[1], trend)), I am guessing that trend is a series. is that right?
(3) Where I have the main problem is on the third statement... how the condition is checking for the value of trend and depending on the condition the result is assigned to the trend.  Is this a loop? Even if it is a loop, trend never can have a value of -1. I am sure that I am missing something.

I will appreciate very much any help.  THANK YOU.

Comment: `trend` is an integer variable (not a constant, since its value changes several times in the script). `nz` "returns the second argument if the first is equal to `na`" https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v3/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#preventing-na-values-functions-na-and-nz

Comment: line 3 is not a loop, it's a series of conditional (boolean) expressions see https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v3/language/Operators.html#conditional-operator-and-the-function-iff

Comment: if trend is an integer variable, what is trend[1]? I know that [1] means previous value of a series. But trend is integer variable, how does it can have a previous value unless is a series (array).  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can write that third line as

```
trend := if (trend == -1 and close > dn1)
    1
else
    if (trend == 1 and close < up1)
        -1
    else
        trend // keep its value
```

Now, for the very first bar of the chart, `trend` will be `na` and that's where the `nz()` function kicks in. It will replace the `na` with `trend` which is defined as `1`.

So, when you come to the third line, `trend = 1`. Then this `(trend == 1 and close < up1)` condition will be checked and if `close < up1` is `true`, `trend` will be `-1`.

Here is a simple code that will make the `trend` `1` when it is a green bar, and `-1` when it is a red bar.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script")

dn1 = close[1]
up1 = close[1]

trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)

trend := if (trend == -1 and close > dn1)
    1
else
    if (trend == 1 and close < up1)
        -1
    else
        trend // keep its value

plot(trend)
```

[image]